Docker compose watch service crashes
Docker compose seems not to behave properly when using --watch option.
This is my tree:
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── service
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── package.json
    └── src
        └── index.js

docker-compose.yml
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: ./service
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync+restart
          path: ./service
          target: /node_workdir
    command: npm run test

Dockerfile
FROM node:latest

# Use a specific user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/sh -u 1001 node_user
USER node_user

# Set workdir and install dependencies
WORKDIR /node_workdir
COPY --chown=node_user:node_user . .

package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./src/index.js"
  }
}

index.js
setInterval(() => console.log(new Date().toUTCString()), 500);

Running this with docker compose up --build --watch will success with this output to console:
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Network docker-compose-watch-example_default      Created                                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container docker-compose-watch-example-service-1  Created                                                                                     0.0s 
Attaching to service-1
           ⦿ Watch enabled
service-1  | 
service-1  | > test
service-1  | > node ./src/index.js
service-1  | 
service-1  | Sat, 31 Aug 2024 10:09:19 GMT
service-1  | Sat, 31 Aug 2024 10:09:20 GMT

But when I modify the contents of index.js, the container crashes with this output:
service-1  | Sat, 31 Aug 2024 10:10:00 GMT
service-1  | Sat, 31 Aug 2024 10:10:01 GMT
           ⦿ Syncing "service" after changes were detected
[+] Restarting 0/1
[+] Restarting 0/1r-compose-watch-example-service-1  Restarting                                                                                  0.2s 
 ⠼ Container docker-compose-watch-example-service-1  Restarting                                                                                  0.5s 
service-1  | npm error path /node_workdir
service-1  | npm error command failed
service-1  | npm error signal SIGTERM
service-1  | npm error command sh -c node ./src/index.js
service-1  | npm notice
service-1  | npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.8.2 -> 10.8.3
service-1  | npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.3
service-1  | npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.3
[+] Restarting 1/1otice
 ✔ Container docker-compose-watch-example-service-1  Started                                                                                     0.8s 
service-1 exited with code 0
           ⦿ Watch disabled
~/Desktop/docker-compose-watch-example ➤ a02f451|master
9184 ± :                                                    

I am not sure if this is something to report, or a misconfiguration issue. Any help will be welcome.

For me it started working when i changed the starting command from:
docker compose up --watch
to:
docker compose watch

For me if I run it as docker compose watch is not logging the date to the console.
EDIT: Of course is not logging anything, it is documented in https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/

As this seems an inconsistency between docker compose watch and docker compose up --watch we filed a bug on https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/12096

Came just here after googling the same. For me the 'watch' is working correctly, it synces over the data and restarts the container but then the watch stops, and doesn't recognize new changes.
    ~/Documents/Projects/nodered-exact    main !4 ?1 ──────────────────────────────── 19:28:30  
❯ docker compose up --watch           
WARN[0000] /Users/riekus/Documents/Projects/nodered-exact/docker-compose.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container nodered-exact-node-red-1  Running                                                       0.0s 
Attaching to node-red-1
            ⦿ Watch enabled
            ⦿ Syncing "node-red" after changes were detected
node-red-1  | 31 Aug 17:29:03 - [info] Stopping flows
node-red-1  | 31 Aug 17:29:03 - [info] Stopped flows
[+] Restarting 1/1
 ✔ Container nodered-exact-node-red-1  Started                                                       0.5s 
node-red-1 exited with code 0
            ⦿ Watch disabled

    ~/Documents/Projects/nodered-exact    main !4 ?1 ─

develop:
  watch:
    - action: sync+restart
      path: ./node-red-contrib-exact-online
      target: /usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-exact-online
      ignore:
        - node_modules/


Yes, this is exactly the issue.

The docker compose watch works as intended. The problem is that its intended behavior is to disable logs in the console. And I would like to have them using docker compose up --watch, which should work.
